# Why does not show the description of mediaValue in OpenApi?

Tags: spring-boot, multipartform-data, swagger-ui, openapi

I used `springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui` in spring boot to make documentation for my API.
I write descriptions for all properties but `mediaType` with type `MultipartFile` not show the description.

```java
package com.ayah.poll.component;

import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema;

public class UpdateCommentModel {

    private Long pollId;
    private Long commentId;
    private String textValue;
    private boolean deleteTextValue;
    private MultipartFile mediaValue;
    private boolean deleteMediaValue;

    @Schema(name = "pollId", description = "The poll for updated comment.", example = "35", type = "number", required = true)
    public Long getPollId() {
        return pollId;
    }

    @Schema(name = "commentId", description = "The comment that you want to updte it.", example = "7", type = "number", required = true)
    public Long getCommentId() {
        return commentId;
    }

    @Schema(name = "textValue", description = "The new text value, it is `mandatory` if `mediaValue` does not exist or deleted.", example = "Hello world", required = false)
    public String getTextValue() {
        return textValue;
    }

    @Schema(name = "mediaValue", description = "The new Image, it is `mandatory` if `textValue` does not exist or deleted.", required = false)
    public MultipartFile getMediaValue() {
        return mediaValue;
    }

    @Schema(name = "deleteTextValue",defaultValue = "false", description = "True when you want to delete textValue and retain mediaValue or add new one", example = "true",type="boolean", required = false)
    public boolean isDeleteTextValue() {
        return deleteTextValue;
    }

    @Schema(name = "deleteMediaValue",defaultValue = "false", description = "True when you want to delete mediaValue and retain textValue or add new one", example = "true",type="boolean", required = false)
    public boolean isDeleteMediaValue() {
        return deleteMediaValue;
    }
    
}
```

and this is the result:
[image]

expected result show description for `mediaValue`